proxy settings in the quasar.config.js file does not work
While developing, quasar devruns a server at the port 9000. I want to make an axios request to an other server running on the port 8082.
I added a proxy to the devServer in the quasar.config.js
proxy: {
        // proxy all requests starting with /api to jsonplaceholder
        '/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:8082',
          changeOrigin: true,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
          /*
          pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': ''
          }
          */
        }
      }

According to this, although a request to the relative url /api/bank must be sent to the http://localhost:8082/bank the request is going to the http://localhost:9000/api/bank
I am trying to send an axios request to the address localhost:8082 from dev server running at the localhost:9000 and I expect that the request will be go to the server localhost:8082

I found the cause of the problem. The nodejs v21 was installed on my machine. I downgraded it to the v20. Now everything is fine.
